# Identifying weeks from complex date format

Tags: r, datetime, format

I have a pretty annoying format for the dates in a data frame. here is a sample:

```
"Jan 1, 2020, 8:36:55 PM"  "Jan 7, 2020, 12:00:00 PM" "Jan 9, 2020, 8:24:55 PM"
```

The first thing I had to do was to filter it by year. I ended up just using `grep()`, since there is no other context in which 2020 appears, but this isn't an elegant solution. I hope the answer to my current problem can help with this, too.

Anyway, I now want to identify the weeks. I want to take the sum of each cell of a different column by week. However, I don't even know how to turn that character string into some sort of date...

Just to give you a sample of my data, it would be this (already filtered for 2020):

```
               Activity.Date Moving.Time
1    Jan 1, 2020, 8:36:55 PM        3581
2   Jan 7, 2020, 12:00:00 PM        1200
3    Jan 9, 2020, 8:24:55 PM         970
4   Jan 12, 2020, 7:51:30 PM        5564
5    Feb 4, 2020, 9:20:21 AM        1350
6    Feb 5, 2020, 9:20:00 AM        2400
7    Feb 6, 2020, 9:15:00 AM        2415
8  Feb 16, 2020, 11:55:51 AM        1836
9   Feb 17, 2020, 8:36:47 PM         511
10  Feb 25, 2020, 7:30:00 PM         928
11   Mar 4, 2020, 7:41:02 PM         558
12   Mar 6, 2020, 8:25:27 PM        2637
13   Mar 9, 2020, 8:37:11 PM         577
14  Mar 11, 2020, 7:46:10 PM         523
15 Mar 11, 2020, 10:00:25 PM        1278
16 Mar 12, 2020, 12:34:41 AM         442
17  Mar 13, 2020, 8:26:55 PM        2410
18  Mar 16, 2020, 8:25:22 PM         609
19  Sep 12, 2020, 7:27:26 PM        1884
20  Sep 15, 2020, 7:46:27 PM        1783
21  Sep 17, 2020, 8:41:19 PM        1838
22 Sep 19, 2020, 12:08:56 PM        1995
23  Sep 22, 2020, 7:29:01 PM        1776
24  Sep 24, 2020, 7:08:35 PM        1972
25  Sep 26, 2020, 7:24:52 PM        4032
26   Oct 3, 2020, 7:27:22 PM        4172
27   Oct 7, 2020, 8:00:41 PM        2987
28   Oct 8, 2020, 6:57:21 PM        2319
29  Oct 10, 2020, 7:23:39 PM        2509
30  Oct 12, 2020, 6:54:36 PM        5711
31  Oct 13, 2020, 7:56:59 PM        1764
32  Oct 14, 2020, 7:18:06 PM        4822
33  Oct 15, 2020, 8:09:31 PM        1863
34  Oct 17, 2020, 7:50:45 PM        5086
35  Oct 20, 2020, 7:58:39 PM        1583
36  Oct 21, 2020, 8:16:10 PM        4978
37  Oct 22, 2020, 7:23:26 PM        1940
38  Oct 22, 2020, 8:18:24 PM        1857
```

EDIT: I also need the number of rows that were summed in a third column, if possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as.POSIXct`.

```
x <- c("Jan 1, 2020, 8:36:55 PM",  "Jan 7, 2020, 12:00:00 PM", "Jan 9, 2020, 8:24:55 PM")
as.POSIXct(x, format = '%b %d, %Y, %I:%M:%S %p', tz = 'UTC')
#[1] "2020-01-01 20:36:55 UTC" "2020-01-07 12:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-09 20:24:55 UTC"
```

The formats are mentioned in `?strptime`.

If this is difficult to remember you can use `mdy_hms` from `lubridate`.

```
lubridate::mdy_hms(x)
```

---

Once you do that you can extract the week information and `sum` `Moving.Time` in each week.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(Activity.Date = mdy_hms(Activity.Date)) %>%
  group_by(Week = week(Activity.Date )) %>%
  summarise(Moving.Time =  sum(Moving.Time))
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. But is there a way for me to also add a column with how many rows were summed? I hadn't realised I'd need it, before...

Comment: You can use `n()` to count number of rows in each week. Change the last line to `summarise(Moving.Time =  sum(Moving.Time), count = n())`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your activity.date column to a date/time object with this:

```
activitydate <-as.POSIXct("Jan 1, 2020, 8:36:55 PM", format="%b %d, %Y, %r")
```

Then to identify the week number:

```
format(activitydate, "%V") #or %U
```

See help for `strptime` for more information.

**Update**
To answer your second question about providing number of the rows this is easily done with the dplyr library.

```
df$Activity.Date <- as.POSIXct(df$Activity.Date, format="%b %d, %Y, %r")
df$week <- format(df$Activity.Date, "%V")

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(week) %>% summarize(count=n(), sum=sum(Moving.Time))
```